# Как в mysql получить все записи по заданному дню, но в каждом месяце и году?

Tags: mysql, sql

Например, нужно получить данные за 25 число каждого месяца и года. Или за другой заданный день (не путать с датой, требуется именно число). Структура примерно такая:

```
CREATE TABLE `ut_treby_order` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: https://oracleplsql.ru/mysql-function-day.html или https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day

Comment: Там нет ответа на заданный вопрос

Comment: Есть. Вчитайтесь внимательно. Там приведена функция, которая получает день из даты. Остаётся только в условие выборки подставить нужное число

Comment: День из даты не нужно получать. Нужно только составить условие выборки правильно.

Comment: `WHERE DAY(дата)=25` и где вы тут видите что не нужно?

Comment: Теперь понял, как это сделать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `ut_treby_order` 
WHERE DAY(`datetime`) = 25
```